# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, ajaxform

I wanted to replace my html with the new Ajax response html but this error shows in the console and my script files are not loading correctly. Apparently this error comes in the file "jquery-1.10.1.min.js". Following is my ajax code which I used to replace with the html in the success function.

```
$(function() {
         $('#addcustomer-done').click(function() {

       var formData = new FormData($('#submit_form')[0]);

       //---------------------- AJAX CALL 1 -----------------------------------------//
       $.ajax({
            // headers : {
                      // 'X-CSRF-Token' : document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
                  // },
            url : "/savecustomer/",
            type : "POST",

             data:formData,
             contentType: false,
             cache: false,
             processData: false,
             async: false,

             cache:false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,


            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);

                $("html").html("");
                $("html").html(data);
            }
```

I'm a beginner at ajax. Kindly guide me how to get rid of this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove async:false from ajax

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Still same error.

Comment: dont clear the elements inside html tags. USe $("body").append(data);

Answer (score 0):

Dont clear the elements inside html tags. Use an element present in the dom to append the value. Also remove `async:false` from your ajax. Because ajax should run asynchronously.

```
$(function() {
    $('#addcustomer-done').click(function() {
        var formData = new FormData($('#submit_form')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/savecustomer/",
            type: "POST",

            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#id of element inside tab").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that removed the error but it refreshed my whole page. I'm actually using bootstrap form wizard and I want to remain at the specific tab and just reload the page without refreshing the whole thing.

Comment: see the edit. give id or class to an element inside the tab. And append value into it

Comment: To make it clear, I have a dropdown select that needs to be updated once I add a customer.

Comment: I tried          $('#tab2').replaceWith($(data).find("#tab2").html()); and it worked fine. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The above line of code is bit buggy. Try this one $('#replace-div').html($(data).find("#replace-div").html());